# error C3083: '_String_base': el símbolo situado a la izquierda de '::' debe ser un tipo

Tags: c++

primeramente agradecerles su gran colaboración

```
error C3083: '_String_base': el símbolo situado a la izquierda de '::' debe ser un tipo
error C2039: '_Xlen' : no es un miembro de 'std'
error C3861: '_Xlen': no se encontró el identificador
error C3083: '_String_base': el símbolo situado a la izquierda de '::' debe ser un tipo
error C2039: '_Xran' : no es un miembro de 'std'
error C3861: '_Xran': no se encontró el identificador
```

he tenido el inconveniente que menciono tratando de compilar este código y no logro entender por que el error si alguno me pudiera colaborar y darme un ejemplo,

```
 #include <string>

namespace std2013
{
    class _String_base2013
    {
    public:
        static void _cdecl _Xlen2013(void);
        static void _cdecl _Xran2013(void);
    };
};

void _cdecl std2013::_String_base2013::_Xlen2013(void)
{
    std::_String_base::_Xlen();
}
void _cdecl std2013::_String_base2013::_Xran2013(void)
{
    std::_String_base::_Xran();
}
```

Comment: Creo que te está diciendo que `_String_base` no pertenece al espacio de nombres `std`.

Comment: O bien te falta algún include o estás equivocando el uso del espacio de nombres